# How can i get categories against parent category id and their subcategories in magento

Tags: php, magento

i want to get subcategories against Specific Parent Category id and their subcategories , i tried below script,

```
$children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories(1234);
                        foreach ($children as $category) {
                           $parent_cat[] = $category->getName();

                        }
                        echo '<pre>';
                           var_dump($parent_cat);
                           exit();
```

Through above script i got all subcategories against Parent Id, but i also want  subcategories of all subcategories which i got from parent id. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, i found solution myself :-)

```
$cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories(140);
                    //$subcats = $cat->getChildren();
                        foreach ($cat as $category) {
                           $parent_cat[] = $category->getName();
                            $cat_id = $category->getChildren();
                               foreach ($cat_id as $sub_category_id){
                                    $sub_cat[] = $sub_category_id->getName();
                                }
                        }
```